# The authentication callback function is not triggered in Auth0 Lock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, token, jwt, auth0

I have a scenario that I want to sign in into my application using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/). I have included a CDN link to Auth0 Lock version `10.3.0` in my project and I'm then using it like this:

```
let options = {
    disableSignupAction: true,
    rememberLastLogin: false,
    gravatar: false
}

// Show the login form
this.auth0Lock.show(options, (err, profile, token) => {
    if (err) {
        this.$log.error('Login error:', err)
        return reject(err)
    }
});
```

When I choose to login with Google the callback function is not triggered and I'm unable to get the token.

Answer (score -1):

You say you are using version `10.3.0`, but the code you added targets a previous version of Lock. Of particular importance for your example:

> **The `show` method no longer takes any arguments**. You pass the options to the constructor and you listen for an authenticated event instead of providing a callback.

<sub>(emphasis is mine)</sub>

For more information about migrating from a previous version see [Lock 9 to Lock 10 Migration Guide](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/migration-guide).

Additionally, your current callback only has logic for when an error occurred, so you still need to add logic for the success scenario after migrating to the new approach of Lock 10.

Comment: yes but if i include version 9.1 cdn I am getting as:  Social provider API keys are required

When using the popup mode you have to configure your own ClientID and Secret on the social provider.

To do that, go to Social Connections expand the <provider> and configure the keys.

Comment: Where I need to configure the keys

Comment: You can do that through the [Auth0 Dashboard](https://manage.auth0.com/#/); menu on the left: [Connections] -> [Social] and then select the Google one.

Comment: For that we need to enter any thing like client Id or domain name?

Comment: Yes, you need to enter client ID and client secret. See [this for a step-by-step tutorial on how to obtain Google client keys](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/social/google).